# Return Type for recursion in c#

Tags: c#, recursion, return-type

Which return type should we use in c#?Is recursion possible using the "void" return type in c#?

I have a function in which return type is a void, but when I call it, it recursively undergoes Infinite looping, so what is better solution for this:

I am using function as stated below:

```
void A()
{
  //Some code
  A()
}
```

Comment: Return types don't matter; it's the logic that matters.

Answer (score 4):

I think your understanding of recursion needs some sharpening.

Have a closer look at [Recursion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z3dk2cc3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Despite the usefulness of recursion, you can easily create a recursive
>   function that never returns a result and cannot reach an endpoint.
>   Such a recursion causes the computer to execute an infinite loop.
>
> Another problem that can occur with recursion is that a recursive
>   function can use all the available resources (such as system memory
>   and stack space). Each time a recursive function calls itself (or
>   calls another function that calls the original function), it uses some
>   resources. These resources are freed when the recursive function
>   exits, but a function that has too many levels of recursion may use
>   all the available resources. When this happens, an exception is
>   thrown.

Your issue here is not the return type. You need to have some rule for the resursion to end, lets say a depth of recustion call, or a number of directories as a max to recurs.

Maybe also have a look at [Recursive methods using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142292/Recursive-methods-in-Csharp)

Answer (score 1):

Every recursive method sequence must be somehow terminated. Often the first part of the recursive method will have a branch that tests for a condition being met. In this way, the recursive methods continue until the result is attained.
for example

```
static int Recursive(int value)
    {       
    if (value >= 10)
    {
        // throw new Exception("End");
        return value;
    }
    return Recursive(value + 1);
    }
```

There is nothing to do with  the return type. if conditions are not supplied your function will go to infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling the same function, it is obvious it will go in infinite loop. After a condition is satisfied you need to come out of this loop and that can be achieved by using `break` keyword.

Comment: A `break` won't break you out of an infinite loop caused by recursion.